# Contesting a Closed Question Marked As Duplicate

Tags: discussion, support, questions, duplicate-questions

I came across a question today that i was in the process of answering:

[Searching All Columns of a single Table for a Value In a Single Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241929/searching-for-a-certain-important-value-regardless-of-the-column)

But before i could post the answer it was marked as a duplicate.  The links to the duplicate questions that are supposed to answer it though are not the appropriate places for me to post my answer.  Those questions are asking a general question of how do I find a value in all fields in all tables in a database.  This poster wants to know how to find all fields in just one table in a simple select statement without knowing all the column names.

What is the process for contesting a question that is closed to get it reopened?

Comment: Ha! My meta question about duplicates was marked as a duplicate.  So very meta meta!   I really did search to see if my question was already answered, but i think i was looking for "contested" instead of "opposed".  Thanks.

Comment: This is pretty funny!

Answer (score 3):

If the question is different from the duplicate it is closed as, then edit the question to distinguish it from its duplicate.

Note that editing it to just *state* that it's not a duplicate isn't helpful, rather edit the question to make it clear *why* it's not a duplicate.

If this question is only interested in a single table, rather than all, then edit the question to *say that*, so that the reader will understand that they don't need to address the harder problem of handling all tables.

The edit will push the post into the reopen queue, where if the reviewers determine that the edit now sufficiently distinguishes the posts such that they're not duplicates, they'll reopen it.  If they feel that, despite that, the questions are still duplicates, it'll stay closed.

You also can (and have) posted a comment on the question to discuss the closure.  Here you can potentially discuss the specifics of the closure without detracting from what the question is actually asking.